# When I do I need to provide ./ for current directory in bash

Tags: bash

I was writing a bash script recently and wondered when it is actually needed to populate the current directory determiner.

```
if [ ! -f .env ]; then
fi
```

or

```
if [ ! -f ./.env ]; then
fi
```

is the latter needed at all? If so, when, whats the difference?

Comment: For relative files to the application, probably not needed. To specify which instance of a duplicated executable binary name, yes

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's usually a bad idea to have `.` in the `PATH`. So when you want to run programs from the current directory you need to use the `./` path prefix so the command interpreter knows that the program should be found in the current directory.

---

`PATH` is and environment variable listing the command search path. The shell will use it to search for programs. You can print it with `echo $PATH`.

If you have a command or program that's not in one of the directories listed in `PATH`, then you need to explicitly proved the (full or relative) path to the command or program. For example `/usr/local/bin/somecommand`.

Now lets say that in your current directory (`.` is always the "current" directory, no matter which directory you're in) you have a program called `foo`, then to execute it you need to use `./foo`.

***However*** if you *don't* want to execute the program `foo` in your current directory, for example you just want to list it with `ls -l`, then you don't need to specify the directory prefix `./` since it will look in the current directory.

So, to run the program `foo` in the current directory:

```
./foo
```

To only list `foo` in the current directory:

```
ls -l foo
```

Both `./foo` and `foo` is the same file. The difference is that command execution doesn't automatically look in the current directory. For every other case it's matter of personal style and choice which variant you use.

Comment: Sorry this question might be a stupid one, but I don't entirely understand. Both versions work perfectly fine for me, so when does it trigger problems. Also, how does it apply with non hidden files, let's say `some_script.sh`

Comment: @supersize Updated answer. And please go find a Linux/Unix tutorial or two, as they will probably explain the difference much better than I could.

Answer (score 0):

Some cases where you really need `./foo` instead of `foo` *as an argument*:

1. To prevent an argument from being used as an option

   ```
   $ touch -f   # touch treats -f as an option
   $ touch ./-f  # touch works on a local file named -f
   ```
2. For uniform handling of path names in a loop

   ```
   for x in ./foo bar/baz; do
     dir=${x%%/*}  # . for ./foo, bar for bar/baz
     ...
   done
   ```
3. To prevent `PATH` lookup

   ```
   $ . ./ls  # Source a file named "ls" in the local directory
   $ . ls    # Attempt to source a file named "ls" somewhere in your path
             # (which will fail, since ls is almost certainly not a shell script)
   ```

   This is a generalized case of [what Some programmer dude mentions](https://stackoverflow.com/a/53614317/1126841).